# Pass arguments with page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS page.evaluate() to do some scraping. My problem is that the code I pass to the webkit page is sandboxed, and so has no access to the variables of my main phantom script. This makes it hard make the scraping code generic.

```
page.open(url, function() {
  var foo = 42;

  page.evaluate(function() {
    // this code has no access to foo
    console.log(foo);
  });
}
```

How could I push arguments into the page?

Comment: I believe you may find this answer more sufficient: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524130/phantomjs-does-not-take-arguments-to-function-passed-to-page-evaluate

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I've had that exact problem. It can be done with a little trickery, because `page.evaluate` also can accept a string.

There are several ways to do it, but I use a wrapper called `evaluate`, which accepts additional parameters to pass to the function that must be evaluated on the webkit side. You would use it like this:

```
page.open(url, function() {
  var foo = 42;

  evaluate(page, function(foo) {
    // this code has now has access to foo
    console.log(foo);
  }, foo);
});
```

And here is the `evaluate()` function:

```
/*
 * This function wraps WebPage.evaluate, and offers the possibility to pass
 * parameters into the webpage function. The PhantomJS issue is here:
 * 
 *   http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=132
 * 
 * This is from comment #43.
 */
function evaluate(page, func) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
    var fn = "function() { return (" + func.toString() + ").apply(this, " + JSON.stringify(args) + ");}";
    return page.evaluate(fn);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This source code clearly explained how it works.

Comment: For an in-depth explanation as to why this happens, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222856/passing-arguments-to-anonymous-function-inside-page-includejs-and-page-evaluat

Comment: Your solution seems to be good, but what if I want to pass callback, is it possible? Two days went to garbage. Is there in JS callback global object like arguments?

Answer (score 75):

The change has been pushed and now you can use it as

```
page.open(url, function() {
  var foo = 42;

  page.evaluate( function(foo) {
  // this code has now has access to foo
  console.log(foo);
  }, foo);
}
```

The push details are here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/81794f9096

Comment: this is the best way to do it in case the object you pass is not complex, like a function and etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example of passing multiple arguments?

Comment: For those wanting to pass multiple arguments, have you tried using an array as single argument?

Answer (score 15):

You can pass in the arguments to the function as arguments to page.evaluate.

Example:

```
page.evaluate(function(arg1, arg2){
    console.log(arg1); //Will print "hi"
    console.log(arg2); //Will print "there"
}, "hi", "there");
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the solution that works with PhantomJS 0.9.2 and 0.2.0:

```
page.evaluate(
    function (aa, bb) { document.title = aa + "/" + bb;}, //the function
    function (result) {}, // a callback when it's done
    "aaa", //attr 1
    "bbb"); //attr 2
```

Comment: This is probably not directly for PhantomJS, but a bridge between node.js and PhantomJS. Such bridges use slightly different syntax.

Comment: This answer is the ticket if you are trying to pass argument into the sandboxed evaluate method in the [phantomjs-nodejs bridge](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node). The documentation is still fresh. I almost gave up until I found this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: pass the variables in with the url. For example, to pass object x

```
// turn your object "x" into a JSON string
var x_json = JSON.stringify(x);

// add to existing url
// you might want to check for existing "?" and add with "&"
url += '?' + encodeURIComponent(x_json);

page.open(url, function(status){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        // retrieve your var from document URL - if added with "&" this needs to change
        var x_json = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1));
        // evil or not - eval is handy here
        var x = eval('(' + x_json + ')');       
    )}
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't work in PhantomJS, because `page.evaluate()` is sandboxed.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
page.evaluate("function() {document.body.innerHTML = '" + size + uid + "'}");
```

Means to put everything as a string. Anyway later it become a string. Check the library source.

Answer (score 1):

While you can pass arguments into [evaluate(function, arg1, arg2, ...)](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html), this is often a little cumbersome. Especially in cases when passing in several variables, or worse, functions.

To get around this obstacle, one can use [injectJs(filename)](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) instead.

```
page.open(url, function() {
    if ( webpage.injectJs('my_extra_functionality.js') ) {
        page.evaluate( function() {
            // this code has access to foo and also myFunction();
            console.log(foo);
            console.log(myFunction());
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failed to inject JS");
    }
}
```

---

Where `my_extra_functionality.js` is a local file in the same directory:

```
var foo = 42;
var myFunction = function(){
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

Comment: in case someone is looking for a puppeteer solution, you can use `await page.addScriptTag({path: "/path/to/file/with/extra/functionality"});`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just bind the args to the function??

```
page.evaluate.bind(args)(callbackFn)
```