# CasperJS - Get generated source after document/jquery fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I am having trouble parsing a page with CasperJS.  It seems like the this.evaluate() function only handles the source code.  However, the page I am looking at uses jQuery to add classes to specific elements after the document has been fully loaded.

**How can I use CasperJS to evaluate the generated source after page is fully loaded / ready.**

```
casper.start(url);

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Chrome/30.0.1599.101');
casper.viewport(1920, 20000);

casper.on('load.finished', function(resource) {
    this.evaluate(getSelectedItems);
});

casper.run();
```

.

This is the code that I am currently trying to use within my this.evaluate(getSelectedItems) function.  I just want to detect how many selected items there are, but the source code doesn't contain **.selected-item**.  That class is generated after the full page load with jQuery.

```
function getSelectedItems() {
    return document.querySelector('.selected-item').length;
}
```

Comment: that implies u would return an array of items, u cant call innerHTML on an array

Comment: in my first example, even with multiple items on the page, it would of selected first valid item it found in the code and returned it's innerHTML.  I updated question to better suit my needs.  Thanks

Comment: Is `getSelectedItems` in the client scope or the PhantomJS scope? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222856/passing-arguments-to-anonymous-function-inside-page-includejs-and-page-evaluat/12223183#12223183

Comment: @nrabinowitz - not exactly sure what you mean.  I know CasperJS utilizes PhantomJS and because I am calling this.evaluate, I take it CasperJS is calling over to PhantomJS.  However, I am not injecting jQuery into the page, jQuery already lives on the page I am trying to parse.

Comment: ...sorry, thought that `getSelectedItems` might not have been in scope. But that's probably not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are not available right away, [wait for them](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector):

```
casper.waitForSelector('.selected-item', function() {
    this.echo(this.evaluate(getSelectedItems));
});
```

Comment: Thank but, I tried that and it ends up timing out.  Have you been able to verify that in your script that it works?

Comment: I can't verify without knowing what you're scraping, but I use CasperJS to look for classes added asynchronously all the time, using this or similar `waitFor` methods. Likely suspects if this doesn't work are a bad scraping function or a bad selector...