# Pass a function to nighmarejs evaluate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to pass a function to be called inside the nightmarejs evaluate statement and return a value. Something like this:

```
var thisfunction = function() {
    var tags = [];
    var list = document.querySelector('#selectSomething');
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        tags.push({
            name: item.attributes[1].value,
            id: item.attributes[2].value
        })
    });
    return tags;
};

return nightmare
    .goto('url')
    .wait('#something')
    .evaluate(function(getValues) {
        getValues();
    }, thisfunction)
    .then(function(list) {
        console.log(list);
    })
```

I'm getting `ReferenceError: getValues is not defined`. Tried different approaches with return statements in various place, but no luck.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you can simply write the following code:

```
var thisfunction = function() {
    var tags = [];
    var list = document.querySelector('#selectSomething');
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        tags.push({
            name: item.attributes[1].value,
            id: item.attributes[2].value
        })
    });
    return tags;
};

return nightmare
    .goto('url')
    .wait('#something')
    .evaluate(thisfunction)
    .then(function(list) {
        console.log(list);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

### Reason Behind the Behaviour

You can pass strings/numbers as parameters but not functions/object as they serialised before passing to the evaluate method.

You can checkout the explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12223183/2298362)

Also there is [ticket on Github](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/89#issuecomment-102766944) of users with similar experiences.