# phantomjs global variables call in page.evaluate

Tags: phantomjs

I want to know how to use a varaible globally in phantomjs so that it can be used in the page.evaluate function also.

I have gone through some previous answers but but able to understand well

Comment: This resolved it for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838119/pass-arguments-with-page-evaluate

Answer (score 3):

JSON-serializable arguments can be passed to [page.evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html). 
Here is a very basic the following example using this technique :

```
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function(status) {

  var title = page.evaluate(function(s) {
    return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
  }, 'title');

  console.log(title);
  phantom.exit();

});
```