# PhantomJS does not take arguments to function passed to page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, arguments, phantomjs

I can't pass arguments to function passed to `page.evaluate`. I am trying to submit form.

```
data1 = "Textsample";
page.evaluate(function(data1) {
    var form = document.getElementById ("MyForm");
    form.data.value = data1;
    form.submit();
});
```

But when I'am taking screenshot of page the data field is filled with "undefined". What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass it as 2nd arg in `page.evaluate`.

```
page.evaluate(function(arg){},arg);
```